# assign/retrieve a variable from the Model Workspace from within an S Function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I was wondering if I can assign/retrieve a variable from the Model Workspace from within an S Function? Thanks!

Comment: You can pass the variable in to an s-function as an input or as a parameter but I don't believe you can assign back to the workspace.

Comment: Please specify if you use MATLAB S-functions or C-S-Functions. Also, what have you already tried?